# Kotlin how to check if something is either a or

Tags: kotlin

I want to check

```
if (people.job == Job.Developer || people.job == Job.Scientist) {
    // do Something
}
```

However, it looks ugly to me.

I want something like:

```
if (people.job in (Job.Developer, Job.Scientist)) {
}
```

Comment: What happened to the answer using `when`?  That seemed like a good approach to me.

Comment: @gidds it was deleted by Martin after someone downvoted it... what a pity... I still find it better then to create a list or set...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the answer of [Martin L. Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8480777/martin-l-jensen) was downvoted and deleted by himself, but I think [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) itself is actually still the easiest way to solve this:

```
when (people.job) {
  Job.Developer, Job.Scientist -> println("Fine") // or return a value or whatever
}
```

The benefit in contrast to other shown solutions: no intermediate `Set` or `List` is created which you discard immediately after.

Comment: I can't see Martin's answer, but if that was his answer I'd like to know why it was downvoted. I can't see any drawbacks

Comment: @user2340612 it isn't exactly the same... his answer was actually doing an `else if`, but this could have been perfectly explained/solved as a comment...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`setOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/set-of.html):

```
if (people.job in setOf(Job.Developer, Job.Scientist)) {
    println("Fine")
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out the performance implications of that approach: it creates a new set (which can be quite big), and does a lot more processing than simple comparisons.

Comment: True, but: 1) we cannot really say how it affects application performance without benchmarking (I do not think it will be noticeable), 2) set creation could be moved into a separate variable and most likely it will be reused somewhere else in the application.

Comment: Reusing the set would reduce the object-creation and heap-churn overhead, but it would still need extra processing (calculation of hashcodes &c) and memory access.  And that would use more code than a simple pair of comparisons!  — As you say, the overall impact will depend very much on the application (how often this check is needed, and what else it's doing), but for me it would probably outweigh the slight code advantage unless there were a lot more than two comparisons.

Comment: Probably a matter of taste. If `people.job in setOf(Job.Developer, Job.Scientist)` worth replacing with `people.job == Job.Developer || people.job == Job.Scientist` (in terms of performance) then there is either something terribly wrong with the application or the only thing the application can do is to check if a user job is developer or scientist. I am fine with both options, but `setOf` is more natural, readable and extendable.

Comment: `arrayOf` could be a compromise: faster to create, and for small number of alternatives likely faster to check than `setOf`, not really less readable.